# Generating set of Toric ideal in Integer Programming

Tags: abstract-algebra, integer-programming

I’m stuck with one question to find the generating set of toric ideal.

Here is how the integer programming question is formatted:

```
min 5x+7y+z
s.t. x+6y+8z=24, x,y,z /in N
```

Normally I know we can relax to LP problem and do branch and bound, anyone has any direction on how to solve this in an abstract algebra way?

Comment: Can anyone help with some hints?

Comment: First, you have to decide whether 0 is a natural number. (I vote yes, but apparently it is not an entirely settled matter.) After that, the problem can be solved by inspection, since the naturals are either strictly positive or nonnegative, depending on your interpretation.

Comment: Oh I didn’t notice N means Natual number…then it’s very easy.